# Replacing part of text XML to SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg

I have a script that converts XML to SVG. Now I have a script with which I can replace strings with jQuery, but I want to replace only parts of the text. For instance when I have `Gmaj7` and I want to change it to `Dmaj7`, only the `G` has to be replaced by `D`. How can I do that?

```js
function translatede() {
    $('#m-41 > text:nth-child(1) > tspan:nth-child(1)').text('D');
    $('#m-47 > text:nth-child(1) > tspan:nth-child(1)').text('Dmaj7');
    $('#m-53 > text:nth-child(1) > tspan:nth-child(1)').text('C');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace()` method within a function you provide to the `text()` method. Try this:

```js
$('#m-47 > text:nth-child(1) > tspan:nth-child(1)').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace('G', 'D');
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks. Do you alson know if it's possible to apply this function not only to #m-47 but to change all the 'G's in the document to 'D'? So I don't have to specify all the different id's?

Comment: You can achieve that by putting a class on all those elements and then selecting by that class. You can't really do the whole document at once without recursion.

Comment: That's no problem. In that case I can use the same code, but replace #m-47 by ."nameofclass" ?

Comment: That would depend on your HTML structure, but it should work in the right circumstances

Comment: Doesnot work unfortunately yet. In the xml  I have for all G7 chords: <harm xml:class="chords" xml:id="m-47" staff="1" tstamp="1">G7</harm>

Comment: In that case it would be worth starting a new question giving a full example of your JS and XML.